# Adding onclick event listener within a foreach loop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I am generating and adding html within a for loop and then trying to add onclick events aswell, but for some reason it is not working within the same loop:

```
items.forEach(item => {
  itemHtml = `<div class="${item.id}">${item.id}</div>`;

  $(".itemsWrapper").html($(".itemsWrapper").html() + itemHtml);

  $(`.itemsWrapper > .${item.id}`).on("click", () => {
    console.log(`${item.id} was clicked`);
  });   
})
```

However, if I split that into two forEach loops, it works just fine:

```
items.forEach(item => {
  itemHtml = `<div class="${item.id}">${item.id}</div>`;

  $(".itemsWrapper").html($(".itemsWrapper").html() + itemHtml);
})

items.forEach(item => {    
  $(`.itemsWrapper > .${item.id}`).on("click", () => {
    console.log(`${item.id} was clicked`);
  });   
})
```

Comment: this is cuz jquery dom manipulation are a bit more slow that attaching event to an element, when you do two loops you are giving time to dom to rendering and setting event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do click on the last printed item, the console will show the message. This happens because you're replacing the html with a new one in the second and next iterations, so your event handlers are gone.

```
items.forEach(item => {
    itemHtml = `<div class="${item.id}">${item.id}</div>`;

    // in this line, you're replacing the html from the previous iteration and, in
    // consecuence, deleting the event handlers.
    $(".itemsWrapper").html($(".itemsWrapper").html() + itemHtml);

    // instead of the previous line, you can do something like this and it will work
    // as expected
    $(".itemsWrapper").append(itemHtml);

    $(`.itemsWrapper > .${item.id}`).on("click", () => {
        console.log(`${item.id} was clicked`);
    });   
});
```

Here's a codepen with a working example: https://codepen.io/kmsdevnet/pen/wvzGYpg